# execute commands when notification is clicked within Windows Action Center

Tags: windows, notifications

I have a simple python script that sends a [Windows toast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-notifications-overview) with [this](https://pypi.org/project/win11toast/) lib.

What I want to achieve is to execute some commands when the toast is clicked.

It's easy to do when the click action is done before the toast expired(stay in the right-bottom corner), by registering onActivated event.

However when the toast expired(moved to Action Center), my python script has finished its job and exited(since it's a scheduled light-weighted task).

There's a background activation handling method in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-cpp-uwp?tabs=builder-syntax#handling-background-activation), but I'm dealing with simple python script rather than an app. Is there another solution for this problem?